# headers and boundary included in uploaded file django rest framework

Tags: django, file-upload, django-rest-framework, http-headers

I'm uploading a csv file to Django via ajax, using Django Rest Framework.  I have everything working, but data from the request headers is included with the file content.

I was expecting these headers to have been stripped from the file content, so the file would look exactly like the uploaded file.

Any ideas?

...

Django View

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):    
        file = request.FILES['file']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        fs.save('output.csv', file)
```

input.csv:

```
Date,Customer,Team Member,Services
09-25-2018 03:30 PM,Suzy16 Neil16,Suzy,Men's Haircut | Legs
09-25-2018 03:30 PM,Suzy16 Neil16,Suzy,Men's Haircut | Legs
09-25-2018 03:30 PM,Suzy16 Neil16,Suzy,Men's Haircut | Legs
...
```

output.csv:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarycaNCidFSnOuN1u0G
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="input.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

Date,Customer,Team Member,Services
09-25-2018 03:30 PM,Suzy16 Neil16,Suzy,Men's Haircut | Legs
09-25-2018 03:30 PM,Suzy16 Neil16,Suzy,Men's Haircut | Legs
09-25-2018 03:30 PM,Suzy16 Neil16,Suzy,Men's Haircut | Legs
...

------WebKitFormBoundarycaNCidFSnOuN1u0G--
```

Relevant Headers From HTTP Request:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=services.csv
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarycaNCidFSnOuN1u0G
```

Comment: Is it possible to see the Javascript code that is loading the .csv and making the AJAX call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MultiPartParser` was what I was looking for as the front-end was sending up the form as a multipart form.

```
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    ...
```