# Django Rest Framework: File upload request header and webkit boundary included in saved file using FileUploadParser

Tags: python, django, reactjs, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I'm currently trying to build out a an application with both client-side and server-side code. My frontend is built in React, with my backend being Python/Django, utilizing django-rest-framework.

The feature I'm building out now is a file-upload feature, which utilizes the Dropzone.js library in order to save and store files on the server. Eventually I'd like to be routing the files to AWS S3, but I'm not quite there yet.

My views.py file is currently accepting and saving the file, however the webKitBoundary and file information are also being saved in the file. Optimally, I'd like to be saving the file without having to do file manipulation in order to trim out the unnecessary information.

Here's my **views.py**:

```
class SaveFile(APIView):

authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptJWTAuthentication, )
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )  

def post(self, request, format=None):
     newFile = File()
     newFile.file = request.data['file']
     newFile.save()

    return HttpResponse('file upload success')
```

My file model:

```
class File(models.Model):
   file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'files')

   def __str__(self):
      return self.file.name

   class Meta:
       db_table = "files"
```

My test.txt:

```
hello (.^-^),
```

And the saved result:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryySdQAcRrBj8kluZ5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="yurrr.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

hello (.^-^),
------WebKitFormBoundaryySdQAcRrBj8kluZ5--
```

I've found a similar question here:
[headers and boundary included in uploaded file django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562444/headers-and-boundary-included-in-uploaded-file-django-rest-framework)

However when I try to implement the suggested answer, using MultiPartParser rather than FileUploadParser, my request.data['file'] raises an error, since my request.data is an empty QueryDict. So I can't even process the incoming file.

I'm pretty sure my client-side code is fine, as I'm utilizing a pretty popular library, and in addition, we can see that the file IS being saved. I'd just prefer if **only** the file is being saved, rather than the boundary/request data as well.

Thanks for any help, its much appreciated!

Edit: I’m open to using MultiPartParser instead but just have not been able to seemingly get it to work. Any solution to my issue regardless of the parser class used is fine by me.

Comment: Quick question, What is the problem now and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I’d simply like the saved result to be identical to the uploaded text file, without having to alter the saved file after it has been uploaded.