# How to skip http headers when receiving and writing file from POST request?

Tags: python-3.x, django, file-upload

In my Django POST request, I am getting a json file and writing it locally in the server like this:

```
up_file = request.FILES['file']
full_file_path = <my file path>
destination = open(full_file_path, 'wb+')
        for chunk in up_file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
        destination.close()
```

But the file is written like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary2df6tPQtB97uXIt6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename="input.json"
Content-Type: application/json

{"x": 1}

------WebKitFormBoundary2df6tPQtB97uXIt6--
```

as input.json. Obviously, this is invalid so I want the file to only contain:

```
{"x": 1}
```

How do I make this file writing skip the headers and footers and write only the actual content?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this with the code you have provided in a regular Django view - the file is saved without any content boundaries. There is some context missing from your question in terms of how you're doing this in your project. Are you using DRF view/serializer?

Comment: I am using FileUploadParser to upload file: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser @solarissmoke (no serilalizer, just view)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562444/headers-and-boundary-included-in-uploaded-file-django-rest-framework - you need to use `MultiPartParser`

Comment: @solarissmoke you can't do request.FILES['file'] with `MultiPartParser`. What to do about that?

Comment: NVM found the issue :)